# Why does Longitudinal wave of Infrasound in earthquake not transfer through outer liquid core of earth?

Tags: waves

why Longitudianl wave not transfer through outer liquid core of earth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liquids and solids are almost incompressible. The do compress a microscopic amount under normal pressure, and much more if the pressure is high enough.

Sound is a pressure wave. It can travel through many solids and liquids. When you press on the surface layer of atoms, the layer underneath presses back.

A transverse wave can travel in a solid because the atoms in a solid are rigidly bonded together. If you push an atom in a solid sideways, the atoms around it (in front and to the side) push back. In doing so, they are jostled around and push atoms farther out. The disturbance spreads.

In a liquid, the atoms in front push back more or less because they are in the way. These bump into atoms behind them and the disturbance spreads. But the atoms to the side do not hold on strongly. They are not jostled. They do not disturb atoms behind them.

Comment: SO Longitudina wave may go in liquid but only a litle bit?

Comment: It is more that when waves go in liquid, they go as compression waves.